# Create Dynamic Query in Sybase SELECT TOP X

Tags: variables, sybase, sybase-ase15

I am wondering how to do the following in Sybase 15.

```
DECLARE @DEPTH INT
SET @DEPTH = 8    
SELECT TOP @DEPTH  * FROM Table
```

It gives me the following error :
**Error (102) Incorrect syntax near '@DEPTH'.**

I tried using TOP (@DEPTH), same way as sql server but it recognizes it as an error.

**Error (14216) Function 'TOP' not found. If this is a SQLJ function or SQL function, use sp_help to check whether the object exists (sp_help may produce a large amount of output).**

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

```
DECLARE @DEPTH INT
SET @DEPTH = 8    
SET ROWCOUNT @DEPTH
SELECT * FROM Table
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options:

- wrap the `select` in a pair of `set rowcount` commands (see Adam's answer for an example)
- build a dynamic query and run it via `execute()` (see below for an example)

dynamic query example:

```
declare @depth int, @query varchar(16384)
select  @depth = 8
select  @query = 'select top '+convert(varchar,@depth)+' * from table'
execute(@query)
go
```

Answer (score 0):

TOP accepts only an integer constant, not a variable. In case you are running the very latest (16.0 SP03) you can use ROWS LIMIT @v instead of TOP.

As mentioned by others, you can work around the TOP @v issue by constructing a query dynamically.